# Не видно переменной в xdebug phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Как увидеть текущее значение переменной  в xdebug phpstorm если это последняя строчка кода?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я ставлю что-то ещё в конец кода и брякаю на нём :)

Comment: Да, это работатет, но неужели нет в дебагере штатного решения?

Comment: Ну а какое? Как можно узнать значение переменной **до** того, как в неё занесётся это самое значение?